# Jquery .val() function to check the value of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my logic to check the value of each of the radio buttons. I am using a part of their id's to get hold of the radio buttons. However, my code is always returning a value based on the value of my first radio button. I want it to return the value of each radio button. For example if radio button clicked is yes, then value returned should be 1. Else, 0. Any body who can update my code please.

```
$('.YesNoRadio').each(function() {

    if ($('[id*="YesNo_RadioButtonList_"] input[type="radio"]:checked').val() == 1) {
        //$('[id*="AddAttachment"]').trigger('click');
        $('[id="upload"]').click();
    }

});
```

Html:

```
//For yes radio button
<input id="_YesNo_RadioButtonList_0" type="radio" name="YesNo_RadioButtonList" value="1">
//For no
<input id="_YesNo_RadioButtonList_0" type="radio" name="YesNo_RadioButtonList" value="0">
```

Comment: share html markup

Comment: The `[id*="YesNo_RadioButtonList_"]` selector implies there will be more than one element found, so you probably will need another loop. As @guradio mentioned, we really need to see your HTML. Also `$('[id="upload"]')` should really be `$('#upload')`

Comment: You can't have elements with the same ID (`_YesNo_RadioButtonList_0``)

Comment: I can See you are already iterating Radio Buttons on class `.YesNoRadio` ,  Just `alert( $(this).val());` in `each`  loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect, Remove space from selector. When you use `" "` it indicates you are targeting child elements i.e. [Descendant Selector (“ancestor descendant”)](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

```
if($('[id*="YesNo_RadioButtonList_"]:radio:checked').val() == 1)
   $('[id="upload"]').click();
```

And, You don't need `.each()`

Comment: Thank you. It still didn't do what I was expecting but I managed to tweak it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
//For yes radio button
<input class="YesNoRadio" id="_YesNo_RadioButtonList_0" type="radio" name="YesNo_RadioButtonList" value="1">
//For no
<input class="YesNoRadio" id="_YesNo_RadioButtonList_0" type="radio" name="YesNo_RadioButtonList" value="0">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.YesNoRadio').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert($(this).val());
            //code for yes radio button
            $('[id="upload"]').click();
        }else{
            alert($(this).val());
            //code for no radio button
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A method that worked for me was setting the name in the html input tag the same for each radio button is your list, which you did:

```
<input id="_YesNo_RadioButtonList_0" type="radio" name="YesNo_RadioButtonList" value="1">
<input id="_YesNo_RadioButtonList_0" type="radio" name="YesNo_RadioButtonList" value="0">
```

then I would do this is my JS with JQuery.

```
var radioButtonValue = $("input[name='YesNo_RadioButtonList']:checked").val();
```

This should give you the value of your radio button. The value, in your case, is preset in you input tag.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
$('.YesNoRadio').each(function() {
    if ($('[id*="YesNo_RadioButtonList_"] input[type="radio"]:checked').val() == 1) {
       //$('[id*="AddAttachment"]').trigger('click');
       console.log($(this).val());
       $('[id="upload"]').click();
    }
});
```

Comment: What difference will adding the `console.log()` make? Seems like this should be a comment at best